# Bootstrap Nav now showing on any breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `Bootstrap 3` and obviously I don't want the nav to show by default on mobile, which is working well at the moment, however it is also not showing on *any* screen size.

**My Nav Code:**

```
<div class="nav-holder navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="mr_nav" class="nav-wrap col-xs-12 collapse navbar-collapse">
                <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">

                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Related CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header.main .nav-holder {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: can you reproduce the issue on fiddle

Comment: @JSantosh I tried, but the issue wasn't able to be reproduced on there.